# wso2 : How to read message from Message Store using Message Processor?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, dataservice

I'm trying to read the messages i've stored in my Message store using a processor, by printing it through logs, but i'm unable to.

My Message Processor code (i've included the log and file I want to write to in the testSeq)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor" messageStore="JDBC_MESSAGE_STORE" name="JDBC_MESSAGE_PROCESSOR" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="sequence">testSeq</parameter>
    <parameter name="interval">20000</parameter>
    <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

My proxy that I use to insert values into jdbc message store: (works successfully)

```
<inSequence>
            <iterate continueParent="true" expression="//ns:dbResponse/ns:data" id="Iterate-over-xml" sequential="true" xmlns:ns="http://dss.testdb">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <store messageStore="JDBC_MESSAGE_STORE"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
 <respond/>
</inSequence>
```

Could anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? What is the issue you are having?

Comment: [2023-04-28 17:42:46,555]  INFO {AbstractQuartzTaskManager} - Task scheduled: [ESB_TASK][MSMP_JDBC_MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_0] [Paused].
[2023-04-28 17:42:46,555]  INFO {ScheduledMessageProcessor} - Started message processor. [JDBC_MESSAGE_PROCESSOR].
[2023-04-28 17:42:46,555]  INFO {AbstractQuartzTaskManager} - Task paused: [ESB_TASK][MSMP_JDBC_MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_0]
[2023-04-28 17:42:46,566]  INFO {ScheduledMessageProcessor} - Successfully deactivated the message processor [JDBC_MESSAGE_PROCESSOR]

I get this in the logs, but there are no other errors & I can't print the message store contents.

Comment: These are the only errors you see? The error you see is not the root cause, for some other error, your message processor is getting deactivated.

Comment: Yes, ig so. Is there anything wrong with my message processor code? The testSeq that i've specified is the one where i'm trying to read the messages stored in message store..

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but it turns out I just needed to delete the message processor and restart the esb. It all worked fine then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries! I figured it out, basically since there was an error with the ep sequence that I had specified originally, the processor got deactivated then and remained that way. The solution that worked for me was to delete the message processor xml, restart the ESB and then add the message processor again.